# Combine 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am wanting to combine 2 tables.  until recently the column names were different , and one had fewer columns than the other, however it was deemed unnecessary to have them as two tables.  I have basically made the two tables identical (making them have the same column names and number of columns), and now I need to move the contents of one table into the other.  I'm not quite sure how to perform this, other than my assumption:

```
INSERT INTO table1
   SELECT * FROM table2;
```

I wasn't sure that this was the best way to perform this action.

#

update

would the above query work if say the columns between the two tables are the same, but are in a different order?

Comment: The table1 and table2 should have the same structure but it's the one the best

Comment: @jacques what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variation of your `INSERT INTO ...` query even if the columns are not named the same, and have a differing quantity of columns.  You simply need to name the columns explicity.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordList](
    [Word] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [WordRow] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShortWords](
    [Word1] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [WordRow1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeOtherColumn] varchar(255)
);


INSERT INTO dbo.WordList (Word, WordRow)
SELECT Word1, WordRow1
FROM dbo.ShortWords SW
ORDER BY SW.WordRow ASC;
```

Comment: what if the names are the same but the order is different?

Comment: The order of the columns in the table makes no difference, as long as the column order in the `INSERT INTO` clause and the `SELECT` clause are the same.